# Calling jQuery function once on page load

Tags: jquery, function, events, call, pageload

I have defined a jQuery function, which runs when the input is changed (showing/hiding certain divs). So far so good.

My question: **how do I call this function once when the page loads?**

With my lack of experience I am just making it worse while trying the answers I found so far (dragging the functions outside the document ready declaration, etc.). I guess the functions have to stay where they are, but calling them doesn't seem to work yet. The script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('input[name=project-type]').change(chooseProject);

    function chooseProject() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#div1').hide();    
        $('#div2').hide();
        $('#div3').hide();
        if (val == 'Short') {
          $('#div1').show();
        }
        else if (val == 'Long') {
          $('#div1').show();
          $('#div3').show();
        }
      }

    });
```

Some background: the input is a radio button, and through a multi-step contact form the selected option is remembered on a new pageload, however without the change event the function is not kicking in.

After hours of struggling help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the change event on that element after you have bound it. This executes the handler as if it were triggered naturally by the user.

I would try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //function declaration
    $('input[name=project-type]').on('change', chooseProject);
    $('input[name=project-type]').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying though did not succeed yet. I suspect the reason could be that the input which is remembered is pasted after the page loads, since for a brief moment I can see the default option selected before it switches. I guess the trigger executes too early? Not sure if you have suggestions, I can accept this as it answers the original question.

Comment: If the input is added after you bind the `change` event, it will not work because the element you target with jQuery will not exist at that time (or is replaced with a new element when the page loads). You could bind the event and trigger the change after the input is replaced, though.

Comment: The input element exists, the selected option (value) is changed shortly after the page load. Sorry for not being clear. But if the selected option is changed through another (plugin) script, wouldn't that count as a change event? Or does the user need to select an option manually?

Comment: If the selected option is changed in that way, it does not always trigger the change event in my experience. Is it possible for you to add the `.trigger('change')` after the option is selected through another script? That should work.